# how to detect when i reach bottom of container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch new items when I reached to `bottom`. I am using `infinite scroll hooks`. but it is not loading new data why ?

I tried to make custom hook like that

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useInfiniteScroll = callback => {
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching) return;
    callback();
  }, [isFetching]);

  function handleScroll() {
    if (
      window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !==
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight ||
      isFetching
    )
      return;
    setIsFetching(true);
  }

  return [isFetching, setIsFetching];
};

export default useInfiniteScroll;
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-flower-cib9k?file=/src/App.js

any update ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-smoke-sxucv) codesandbox works for you. If you keep div's height smaller then window `scroll` events wont be triggered on window, you should add event listeners to div's in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Because handleScroll is executed in other closure, and isFetching and setIsFetching are not binded. You can bind it like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll.bind(null, isFetching, setIsFetching);
```

Comment: stll not working https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-flower-cib9k?file=/src/useInfiniteScroll.js